# Inserir um elemento na lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando inserir um novo elemento um uma lista encadeada sem cabeça, eu até consigo inserir mais ao sair da função o ponteiro aponta para nulo novamente

```
void cadastrar_produto(char codProd[], char descricao[], char fornecedor[], char data_validade[], int qtd, double preco, produto *prod){

    produto *p = (produto *) malloc(sizeof(produto));

    strcpy(p->codigo,codProd);
    strcpy(p->descricao,descricao);
    strcpy(p->fornecedor,fornecedor);
    strcpy(p->data_validade,data_validade);
    p->qtd = qtd;
    p->preco = preco;
    p->prox = NULL;

    /* Inserindo o Produto na lista */

    if(prod == NULL){// ele cai dentro desse if sempre
        prod = p;
    }else{

        produto *lst;

        for(lst = prod;lst->prox != NULL; lst = lst->prox){

            puts("for");
            if(comparaString(lst->codigo, p->codigo) == 1){
                puts("Código já cadastrado !!!");
                break;
            }

            if(lst->prox != NULL){
                lst = lst->prox;
            }else{
                lst->prox = p;  
                break;      
            }       
        }
    }

    listar(prod);// ele lista o produto corretamente

    system("pause");
}
```

Eu não estou ver o porquê ele não ficar dentro da lista após sair da função

Answer (score 1):

A questão aqui é que você tem um ponteiro no `main` que passa à função na esperança que a função altere esse ponteiro, com uma atribuição simples mas isso não funciona como imagina.

O cenário simplificado é este (todos os `...` significam o resto do código):

```
void cadastrar_produto(..., produto *prod){
    if(prod == NULL){
        prod = p; // <-- instrução critica
    }
    ...
}

int main(){
    produto *lista = NULL;
    void cadastrar_produto(..., lista); 
    ...
}
```

A instrução `prod = p` altera o parametro `prod` que existe na função e não o ponteiro `lista` que existe no `main` e por isso esse fica sempre a nulo. Lembre-se que os parametros são passados por copia.

Para conseguir alterar o ponteiro tem de passar o endereço do ponteiro, para ir ao local certo na memória e fazer a alteração:

Exemplo (assinalei com comentários todas as linhas que necessitam ser alteradas):

```
void cadastrar_produto(..., produto **prod){
//                                   ^--
    if(*prod == NULL){
//     ^--
        *prod = p;
//      ^--
    }
    else{
        produto *lst;
        for(lst = *prod;lst->prox != NULL; lst = lst->prox){
//                ^--
            ...
}

int main(){
    produto *lista = NULL;
    void cadastrar_produto(..., &lista); 
//                              ^--
    ...
}
```